# On mouse press drag and select textboxes in jquery

Tags: jquery

I just want to fire an event which on mouse key press should select textboxes and change its border-color to black.

How to keep sure that on mousedown event only mouseover event should get fired? Initially, it happens on mousedown: it drags and gets selected.

But after that mouseover gets fired automatically without hit of mousedown function.

Here is my code:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/salok/36h4seeg/)

```
var clicking = false;

$(document).on("mousedown", "[id^='text']", function () {
  $(document).on("mouseover", "[id^='text']", function () {

 $(this).css('border-color', 'rgb(0, 255, 0)');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure you include jQuery in your fiddle, like [so](http://jsfiddle.net/36h4seeg/11/), or add the `<script>` tag:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```